# Как записать байт-код в файл .pyc?

Tags: python, компиляция, интерпретатор

Как сделать, чтобы при запуске файла .py в этом же каталоге автоматически создавался файл с расширением .pyc, который бы содержал в себе скомпилированный байт-код?

Answer (score 0):

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile("hello_world.py", "hello_world.pyc")
```

Comment: Хорошо, а как сделать это без написания дополнительного кода, в каких-нибудь настройках интерпретатора к примеру?

Comment: @VladKvochin никак, вызываемый скрипт не компилируется, только импортируемые модули.